# How to calculate median for multiple split files generated from one big file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to calculate the median for my mouse data set (file name = test). This data set is very big so I split the dataset into multiple files (n=5) with this command:

```
 split -l$((`wc -l < test`/5)) test test.split -da 4
```

After this step, now I have 5 files test.split0000, test.split0001, test.split0002, test.split0003, test.split0004.

I use the following script for calculating the median

```
#!/usr/bin/R

data <- read.table("Input_file", row.names=1, header=T)

M <- apply(data, 1, median) 

write.table(M, "Final_median_mousegene", quote=FALSE, sep="\t", row.names=TRUE)

q()
```

But now I have multiple files so I want to run a single script that works together on all split files.

Thank you

Comment: @Theophrastus: Thank you for getting back. But the reason I split the file is that it was too big to run the median script. I am interested in a bash script that reads all split files one by one and generates different output files for each split file.

Answer (score 1):

"The median is the middle, center or halfway point of a group of numbers. When you order a set of numbers from lowest to highest, the median is the number directly in the middle. Fifty percent of the values in a set occur below the median and 50% are above the median."

So don't use R - just sort the big file, the value halfway is the median value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/usr/bin/R

 files <- list.files(pattern = "test.split*")

 for (i in 1:length(files)){
 data <- read.table(files[i], header=F, row.names = 1)
 M <- apply(data, 1, median) 
 write.table(M, paste0("Median_", files[i]), quote=FALSE, sep="\t", 
 row.names=TRUE)
 }
q()
```